# C# extracting by SevenZipSharp

Tags: c#, .net, archive, 7zip, sevenzipsharp

I try to extract files from an archive, and I have exception 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException'.
I think it can be problem in string, which contains the file name.

```
var cpioExtractor = new SevenZipExtractor(archiveName);
```

I try to input the path to file manually and it doesn't change anything.
Where can be problem?

The stack trace

> in System.String.InternalSubStringWithChecks(Int32 startIndex, Int32 length, Boolean fAlwaysCopy)
>     in System.String.Substring(Int32 startIndex)
>      in SevenZip.Formats.FormatByFileName(String fileName, Boolean reportErrors)
>      in SevenZip.FileChecker.CheckSignature(String fileName, Int32& offset, Boolean& isExecutable)
>      in SevenZip.SevenZipExtractor.Init(String archiveFullName)
>      in SevenZip.SevenZipExtractor..ctor(String archiveFullName)

Comment: What is the stacktrace of the exception you get?

Comment: Also, what is the full message of this exception, and what is the value of its ParamName property?

Comment: archiveName is equals @"E:\GitHub\Repack-Unpack_MTK-Img\Repack-Unpack_MTK-Img\bin\Debug\temp\ram_disk"

Comment: Your 7z archive file name is "ram_disk" (without any extension)?

Comment: Yes, it haven't any exyension

Comment: That's the problem then. If i look at the (current!) source code file which is responsible for archive file name checks in SevenZipSharp ([here](https://sevenzipsharp.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#SevenZip/Formats.cs)), then it become clear that SevenZipSharp complains about **missing** or invalid archive file extensions. Use the constructor overload `SevenZipExtractor(string archiveFullName, InArchiveFormat format)` and specify the correct archive format there. (I hope this helps. I never used SevenZipSharp and just briefly glanced over its source code...)

Comment: Thanks, I solve a problem. Maybe you can suggest another library for working with archive

Comment: Unfortunately, i can't really :) All i ever worked with are DotNetZip (does not support 7z) and the LZMA SDK itself (more low-level than SevenZipSharp). You can rightfully say that i had not much exposure in that area :)